# Error running VLC mediaplayer on Raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, media-player, mp4, vlc, python-vlc

I'm running some media files in my Raspberry, with this code:

```
while True :
    try:
        response = input
        print(response)
        if (response=='playvideo1'):
            print("playvideo1") #first condition I need
            player= vlc.MediaPlayer('/home/pi/Downloads/video1.mp4')
            player.play()
            player.set_fullscreen(True)
        elif(response=='playvideo2'):
            print("playvideo2") #second condition that I need
        elif(response=='playvideo3'):
            print("playvideo3") #third condition that I need
    except:
        pass
```

It runs and plays the video but in the terminal is giving me this error:

```
playvideo1
[a1526cc8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: CMA
[a1526cc8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
'playvideo2'
playvideo2
[00dfbd10] xcb_window window error: X server failure
```

Also, there is some way to play a video if the input is not any of my conditions? like:
 `response ==''`

Comment: you need to set a window id on the mediaplayer

Comment: @mfkl how? I didn't found the documentation. Regards

Comment: https://github.com/videolan/vlc-3.0/blob/e30973a45e8c4f075cf5a6094f500cd3100665f5/doc/libvlc/gtk_player.c#L31